# Send data from server to android application

Tags: android

What is the best manner in which to send data to an android device from a server from an android application? My current setup:

Postgresql database --> program running on server machine --> android device.

I currently am using a custom protocol, but I would ultimately like to make my data source available to the app development community at large. As such, I would like to know the best and most simple options by which I can serve this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read that you need this right away. I have 2 suggestions for you.

1. `HTTP Pooling`. keep the mobile application hitting to server with a defined frequency say 2 minutes in response to hit, server can send the desire information to mobile device. This basically depends on the rate how often you expect the server to contact to mobile application.
2. [RECOMMENDED] Use `TCP mode` of communication between mobile and server. I recommend this because in TCP connectivity, server can `push message` to the mobile application without the mobile application keep on hitting the server.

Comment: hi rohit, I have a local server in my company. I want to setup my .Net web service on that and want to fetch data that resides on server from an android app and vice versa. Is it possible? If it is possible Please let me know about the TCP mode for communication as you wrote above, Please provide any link if it's possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into *Android Cloud To Device Messaging*.  Here's an excellent post from the official developer's blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

Comment: I don't think this is available for immediate use, however. It seems you have to get put on a waiting list for access. Unfortunately I need a more immediate solution..

Comment: This has been depricated. Google cloud messaging is the current one to use.

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Cloud Messaging for Android: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html