# Android : push notification automatic

Tags: android, notifications, push

I've a website and an app connected. The data used by website and app are connected.

I want, when (for example), an user receive a message on the website, he receives a push notification on his app..

How can i do it ?

I know there are services, BUT, how can i do, to use it without check every seconds if the users has receive a message ? (i think it's not a good practice, because it means i call a webservice to check it every time, and i think the battery don't like it :D )

I see there is too GCM, but i really don't understand how does it work...

Thx,

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287218/send-data-from-server-to-android-application

Comment: Yes i saw it ^^ But do you know other tutorials ?